# Set MP Android Y-Axis start point android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid library for rendering line chart. Everything works fine except the starting point of Y-Axis. I have 0 entry for Y for first two X entries and then for third entry I have some value, Graph start drawing from 0,0 location and not directly from third point. I want graph to start from third point.

How can I do that?

Also on Y axis 0 label is shown, Tried to remove that but couldn't find solution. Tried `leftAxis.setStartAtZero(false);` but it doesn't remove 0 label on Y axis and also include a blur line on that point which seems as part of graph

Comment: Do you want to move your view to 3rd point?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Yes I want to move it at 3rd point

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation, [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis) and [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport), I think you have two ways to draw what you want.

- Limit your Y axis to your value. (User won't be able to scroll below this point)

  ```
  yourChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(yourValue);
  ```
- Modify ViewPort to fit your needs:

  ```
  yourChart.moveViewToY(valueCenterOfScreen, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT)
  ```

To remove '0' from your Y Axis, you should use a custom YAxisValueFormatter:

```
    public class MyYAxisValueFormatter implements YAxisValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyYAxisValueFormatter () {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, YAxis yAxis) {
        if (value != 0)
            return mFormat.format(value);
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```